# Collection as key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
var dic = Dictionary<Collection<MyObject>, string>
```

Then I add an entry like this:

```
dic.Add(myObjColl, "1");
```

where myObjColl contains a single entry

On the second run I try to add another entry to dic where myObjColl has two entries (one of them the same as the one in the first run) and I get an exception that the key already exists.

What am I missing here? I expect the dictionary key to be a collection and surely two collections with different number of entries cannot be identical.

EDIT:
What happened was that myObjColl was initialized outside a foreach and during the second iteration updated. So what I thought was a NEW collection with two entries was actually the old one entry collection with an additional entry added.

To elaborate a bit on my issue:

I have a collection of product row objects. Each with a product identification object consisting of a collection of key value pairs:

```
Collection<ProductKeyValuePair> productIdentification;
myProductRow.ProductIdentification = productIdentification;
```

I then have to construct another collection of ProductKeyValuePairs defining the "owner" of each product row object (one product row object can have multiple owners) and I need to add each owner to the correspoding procuct row object(s). A traditional many to many where the common key is a collection of KeyValuePairs.

Hard to explain but it's really down to legacy data returned from old systems running on a mainframe and most likely stored in a hierarchical database of some sort :-/

Comment: It is a little strange to have a collection as key, what is you reason for this?

Comment: Looks a bit like an XY question.. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

Keys in dictionaries are expected to be immutable while they are performing their role as a key. If you do anything to change the value of `GetHashCode()` or `Equals(object)` you will get undefined behavior.

(also if `Collection` does not implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` to use the members it contains it will just do a comparison by reference to the container object itself)

Answer (score 2):

It's not examining the contents of the collection.

It's simply using `myObjColl` (by ref) as the key.

Note: it is very unusual to have a collection as key. Keys are usually strings (or integers).

Comment: Well, actually integers or guids are also nice keys :)

Comment: I know it's unusual but that's what the data requires :-/

Comment: @CJe I find it almost impossible to think of a use case where having a collection be the key is useful, would you please edit your original question explaining why you think the data requires this?

Comment: @CJe just interesting - can you tell why this is required?

Answer (score 0):

To have reference type like collection to be key in dictionary you usually need to pass custom comparer (`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`) to [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) of dictionary. Otherwise default `Equals`/`GetHashCode` implementation of the class is used which normally does not have value semantic (I.e. `string` is sample of reference type that behaves like value).

Overly simplified comparer for collection (no null checks, only compares count) and usage below:

```
class ListSameByCount<T> : EqualityComparer<List<T>>
{

  public override bool Equals(List<T> b1, List<T> b2)
  {
    return b1.Count() == b2.Count();
  }

  public override int GetHashCode(List<T> b1)
  {
    return b1.Count().GetHashCode();
  }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>(new ListSameByCount<int>());
```

Note: collections often bad candidates for keys in dictionary because they can be mutated (items added/removed/changed) and as result hash code would change and dictionary will not be able to find the key.

Comment: If you wanted to you could turn it easily in to `ListSameByMember` by using [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual<T>(IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) in the equals method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - good point. It may be even reasonable O(1) implementation of `GetHashCode` if collections to be used as keys are often of different length.